# How do I add packages to my system when I'm not using the Server edition?

Tags: software-installation, apache2

I have current Ubuntu Desktop for 32-bit installed and want to add apache and some other packages.  I've found some instructions but they are all written for Server where I have a prompt.  How do I do install in a workstation?

Comment: Please explain the question in the title. The information you ask for is broadly available across not only in askubuntu but all internet.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Terminal Emulator to access the prompt you are looking for.  Alt+F2, then type in xterm.  Alternatively look for 'Terminal Emulator' in the Accessories submenu.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu has a software center where you can download some software. The icon on the left that is an orange box opens it up. Some software has to be installed through repositories on the terminal as the root user.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install apache2
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use a terminal. It's the same thing. Press <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> to open a terminal and execute commands.

There's also what's called a TTY available, which will give an environment more like Ubuntu server. To enter one press <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd> through <kbd>F6</kbd>. You'll have to login with your username and password before you can execute commands.

Answer (score 0):

You can open a terminal by pressing (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>).

First, you should **update** the package lists from the repositories. This can be done with

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Then, you can **install** packages by issuing the command:

```
sudo apt-get install package-name
```

You will be asked for your password, and once this has been provided the installation will start.

If you wish to **upgrade** the packages on your machine,

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

will do just that.

Similarly, to **remove** a package, use

```
sudo apt-get remove package
```

As you see, command line syntax is very intuitive, fast to pick up, and very powerful.